# Netbeans/Java scrambling/garbled text rendering

Tags: java, eclipse, button, netbeans, text-rendering

I am running netbeans 8.0.2 (first time netbeans user) and when I run a GUI program, the text on the buttons or frame disappears or gets garbled when I hover over them, like if it had some refreshing problem.

I used Eclipse before and it had the same problem but I set the binary/exe files for eclipse to use my second/dedicated graphics card and that solved the problem. Unfortunately, that did not work on netbeans, and a workaround is to disable cleartype on my windows system, but it's a pain to switch it on and off everytime I'm working in netbeans so I was hoping to find some fixes or better workarounds from the folks here.

So does anyone know a fix? And have you encountered this before?

Here attached is a screenshot of how it looks like
[image: http://imgur.com/x9RPSei]

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix:

-Update your graphics card driver, in my case, an intel HD 4000.
Solved the problem.